# Add code with MIT License to my website

Tags: licensing, open-source-software

If I get HTML code with a MIT License, then I edit the code (for example I change the input box placeholder or something like that), how to put the code in my website legally?

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218331/what-are-the-requirements-for-attribution-in-the-mit-license). So i'll just quote what was said.

> The fourth paragraph says that the copyright notice in the second
>   paragraph must be reproduced. Users of the licence substitute the
>   [fullname] with their actual name. That is what constitutes "proper
>   attribution" in the mind of the MIT: every user of the software can
>   find out who wrote it if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in your website any way you want, just put a comment at the start of the code which includes the license.

Comment: For example the code will be:
// MIT License
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  The code here
</html>

I should just write "MIT License" or Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the....

Comment: Write the whole thing.

Comment: @user7644865 Using `//` to deliminate comments in html is absolutely wrong. `//` is for commenting in php. "//" in html will be rendered in the DOM and will break the doctype. Use `<!--` comments here `-->`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry.